# Httpclient take a very long time

Tags: java, httpclient

I'm trying to download many files using the `Apache HttpComponents library`.

Files are downloaded separately using the same HttpClient.

But I get only the first one. When I use the debugger, the program stay blocked on this instruction

```
HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
```

I'm dowloading files on seperate threads using the ExecutorService :

> ```
>     ExecutorService pool = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
>     pool.submit(new FileDownloader(httpClient,URL1));
>     pool.submit(new FileDownloader(httpClient,URL2));
>     pool.shutdown();
>     pool.awaitTermination(Long.MAX_VALUE, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
> ```

**EDIT**

It works when I use a seperate httpClient.

Any idea ?

Comment: Paste more code, and the url of the GET

Comment: First guess with so little data: blocking I/O. Maybe you need to create a thread for each petition

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was a problem due to the proxy of my company. It doesn't allow more than 2 openened connection in the same time.
So to avoid this problem, don't forget to close the HttpResponse after every request.

Answer (score 0):

The information you've given is rather sparse. I'm guessing that you're using the [Apache HttpComponents library](http://hc.apache.org/). In that case, when using an `HttpClient` from more than one thread, you will need to use a thread-safe connection pool manager.

For instance: `PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager`

See [this tutorial](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/examples/org/apache/http/examples/client/ClientMultiThreadedExecution.java) for an example.

Comment: Yes I'm using Apache HttpComponents library.
I don't think that it's a problem of threads because I'm using a SingleThreadExecutor to run my threads. I'll edit my post to give more information

Comment: I tried to download all files in the same thread and same problem.